# GET chrome-extension://< soundcloud's stream url > net : : ERR_FAILED

Tags: google-chrome-extension, soundcloud, soundmanager2

So I'm trying to stream soundcloud with soundmanager2, but i got this error from my background event page:

```
GET chrome-extension://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/155143944/stream?    
client_id=d47c763873f2jan403dac26b62e3a820 net::ERR_FAILED chrome- 
extension://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/155143944/stream?
client_id=d47c763873f2jan403dac26b62e3a820:1

T/tracks/155143944-0.7370116342790425: HTML5 error, code 4 soundmanager2.js:1191
T/tracks/155143944-0.7370116342790425: Failed to load / invalid sound? Zero-length    
duration reported. (chrome-extension://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/155143944/stream?  
client_id=d47c763873f2jan403dac26b62e3a820) soundmanager2.js:1189
```

Here is my code:

**Manifest**:

```
 "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "*://soundcloud.com/*"
  ],

"background": {
    "scripts": ["soundmanager2/script/soundmanager2.js", "soundcloud_SDK.js",     
                "background.js"],
    "persistent": false
 },
```

**Background.js**:

```
SC.initialize({
    client_id: "d47c763873f2jan403dac26b62e3a820"
});

soundManager.setup({
    url: 'soundmanager2/swf',
    onready: function() {
       SC.stream("/tracks/155143944", function(sound){
        sound.play();
      });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like an issue with [protocol-relative URLs](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/).

Look in the source files for strings like `//api.soundcloud.com/` and put `https:` in front of it.
And maybe also `location.protocol + '//api.soundcloud.com/'` -> `https://api.soundcloud.com/`.

Comment: yup that's it. Thanks a ton, Rob W!